# Launch a program from the destop using jQuery or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, windows, desktop, launch

**Short:**

I was wondering if there is a function or script to launch an application from the user's desktop when clicking on a link (jQuery/PHP).

**Long:**

I'm writing a Ticketing System for work where we have to document the customer data and the problem and such, and i would like to implement something like opening Teamviewer via a button. Because we have to remotly fix most of the problems.

I'm not sure if this is possible due to security reasons and such, but it would be a handy feature to implement.

I know there is a function like 'exec' for PHP but that only works with applications on the server (I think) and Teamviewer is a client side application.

PS. Languages used: JavaScript & PHP.